# is there a way to select a child element of an element using css

Tags: css, css-selectors

example below should comprehend my question.

```
<div id="bmw" class="car">
  <div class="seats">4</div>
  <div class="fuel">petrol</div>
</div>
<div id="merc" class="car">
  <div class="seats">2</div>
  <div class="fuel">petrol</div>
</div>
```

using css can i select `seats` element of `bmw` element. i don wanna add extra class tag to child elements of `bmw`

and how to select seats of all car class elements

```
<div id="bmw" class="car">
  <div class="seats">4</div>
  <div class="fuel">petrol</div>
</div>
<div id="merc" class="car">
  <div class="seats">2</div>
  <div class="fuel">petrol</div>
</div>
<div id="mazda" class="truck">
  <div class="seats">2</div>
  <div class="fuel">diesel</div>
</div>
```

and how to select element with both car and seat classes

```
<div id="godrej" class="car seat">
  <div class="hands">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you don't want to use `.bmw .seats`?

Comment: Please take a look at the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq I don't really think you understand how SO works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #bmw .seat{}

.car .seat{}
```

In the first the rules will apply to all the elements with class seat inside the element with id bmw.

In the second the elements that has both the class car and seat.

```
.car.seats{}
```

This will apply for the element with both in `Class=""` property

```
.car .seats{} //with space in between
```

This will apply for the elements that have parent class as car and child class as seats.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty basic CSS

```
#bmw .seats {
    /* your rules go here */
}
```

See, `#bmw` is an ID selector. `.seats` is a class selector. If you combined them the way posted it will get all `.seats` inside `#bmw`

I think you need to learn more about CSS, this is CSS 101

**Update**

To select all `.seats` inside `.car` simply use

```
.car .seats {
    /* your rules go here */
}
```

Comment: **using css can i select seats element of bmw element. i don wanna add extra class tag to child elements of bmw**

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't see the point. *I don wanna add extra class tag to child elements of bmw* sounds to me like he don't want to modify the markup.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy how to identify seat class element children of only car class elements?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy to select an element with class="car seat"?

Answer (score 1):

```
#bmw .seats {
    /* your can specify styles here */
}
```

you can select any child element of any tag followed by parent element

for which the bmw element styles not applied

you can specify either class or id to apply styles